# Using arrays to calculate distance between co ordinates and set Y axis and scale - D3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, data-visualization

I have x and y co ordinates  which I should be representing in single Y axis.(My idea was to calculate distance between two points and to represent as Y axis. I also have time which i represent in X axis. I tried the following : But how do I use the arrays to fix Y axis scale? Is there anyway that I could acheive this?Kindly help

```
d3.csv("xxx.csv", function(error, data) {

         for (var i=0; i< data.length ; i++)
          {
         datax[i-2] =  Math.sqrt(( data[i].x1 - data[i-1].x1 )* ( data[i].x1 - data[i-1].x1 )
                         + ( data[i].y1 - data[i-1].y1 )* ( data[i].y1 - data[i-1].y1 ));
    datay[i] = d.Time;
         //  }
//  }
```

If I use the following way, I do not have a way to access the index element of array or using 'd' . Or how do I achieve distance calculation using below?

```
 // load data
 d3.csv("xxx.csv", function(error, data) {

 // change string (from CSV) into number format
  data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.x1 = +d.x1;
  d.y1 = +d.y1;
 console.log(d);
 });
```

Example Data :

type      studentId   Time  x1      y1       z1     x2     y2   z2     x3   y3
PositionA   106       92    881.42  371.92  1.05    15.93   0   10.4    1
PositionA   106       92.4  893.87  459     1.05    15.84   0   6.2 1
PositionA   106       92.6  898.98  430     1.05    16.01   0   1.41    1
PositionA   106       92.8  900.1   416.94  1.05    16.6    0   356.62  1
PositionA   106       93    904.1   416.94  1.05    16.85   0   353.85  1
PositionA   106       93.2  920     416.94  1.05    16.43   0   354.27  1
PositionA   106       93.4  925     416.94  1.05    16.43   0   354.27  1

Comment: I have posted the same data for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `forEach` referencing the previous object in the array. Here, I'm creating a new key/value par, named `distance`, from the second object on (the first object, of course, have no previous record to calculate the distance):

```
data.forEach(function(d,i){
    if(i>0){
    d.distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((d.x1 - data[i-1].x1),2)
        + Math.pow((d.y1 - data[i-1].y1),2));
    }
});
```

This is a demo. In this demo, I changed your CSV to the final array of objects created by `d3.csv` (since I can't use a CSV file in SO snippets):

```js
var data = [{"type":"PositionA","studentId":"106","Time":"92","x1":"881.42","y1":"371.92","z1":"1.05","x2":"15.93","y2":"0","z2":"10.4","x3":"1"},{"type":"PositionA","studentId":"106","Time":"92.4","x1":"893.87","y1":"459","z1":"1.05","x2":"15.84","y2":"0","z2":"6.2","x3":"1"},{"type":"PositionA","studentId":"106","Time":"92.6","x1":"898.98","y1":"430","z1":"1.05","x2":"16.01","y2":"0","z2":"1.41","x3":"1"},{"type":"PositionA","studentId":"106","Time":"92.8","x1":"900.1","y1":"416.94","z1":"1.05","x2":"16.6","y2":"0","z2":"356.62","x3":"1"},{"type":"PositionA","studentId":"106","Time":"93","x1":"904.1","y1":"416.94","z1":"1.05","x2":"16.85","y2":"0","z2":"353.85","x3":"1"},{"type":"PositionA","studentId":"106","Time":"93.2","x1":"920","y1":"416.94","z1":"1.05","x2":"16.43","y2":"0","z2":"354.27","x3":"1"},{"type":"PositionA","studentId":"106","Time":"93.4","x1":"925","y1":"416.94","z1":"1.05","x2":"16.43","y2":"0","z2":"354.27","x3":"1"}];

data.forEach(function(d,i){
    if(i>0){
    d.x1 = +d.x1;
    d.y1 = +d.y1;
 d.distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((d.x1 - data[i-1].x1),2)
        +Math.pow((d.y1 - data[i-1].y1),2));
 }
});

console.log(data)
```

Now, you can simply use the property `distance` of your `data` in your dataviz.